# Desinfectar sitio web de phising

Tags: php

Hace un tiempo me hicieron un ataque en mi web, un defacement, me borraron toda la información, vi algo raro en mi hosting y habían creado un subdominio, pues lo elimine y nuevamente coloque mi sitio web restaurando el backup, pero ahora ningun explorador web deja ingresar, dice que es un sitio infectado de phising ¿Podría alguien decirme como puedo desinfectar un sitio web de phishing?

Comment: Lo primero es tener la certeza de que tu sitio ya este limpio al 100%, porque aun asi te podrian dejar "amiguitos" por ahi. Haz probado usar virustotal.com para ver un escaneo del sitio?

Comment: Usabas algún certificado ssl?

Comment: Bueno realmente si usa un certificado de seguridad SSL, según el analisis que resulta es este: BitDefender Phishing site
Fortinet Phishing site
Google Safebrowsing Phishing site

Comment: Puede ser que el certificado ssl este comprometido, una solución podría ser generar nuevamente el certificado ssl.

Comment: La infección esta antes que el certificado de seguridad existiera.